# error al correr la app en android studio : "is not a valid file-based resource name character"

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

buenas simplemente la app no quiso correr mas, y este es el codigo que me sale, ya trate de REHACER todos los fragments (eso fue lo que hice y aun nada)

```
Error:Error: 'C' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\erny\AndroidStudioProjects\OrganizadorJEC\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_Calendario.xml: Error: 'C' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: renombra tu archivo fragment_Calendario.xml !, debe contener letras en minúscula!, saludos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu mensaje de error especifica el problema:

> Error:Error: 'C' is not a valid file-based resource name character:
>   File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or
>   underscore

**Tus recursos deben contener nombres con letras minúsculas con caracteres de la  "a" la "z", pueden contener caracteres numéricos del  "0" al "9", y guión bajo**, renombra tu layout:

```
fragment_Calendario.xml
```

a

```
fragment_calendario.xml
```

---

Revisa también si tienes más recursos nombrados incorrectamente ademas de este layout para evitar problemas.

Comment: WOW siento que te amo, particularmente gracias a ti mi tesis va adelante ^^ (tengo la impresion de que SABES DEMASIADO de android studio) abra forma de que me regales 2 hrs de tu tiempo ? solo quiero preguntar muchas cosas de android que aun mi proyecto traba xD solo eso

Comment: Claro que si Erny que dudas tienes.

Comment: huy!!! base de datos, fragment, implementacion de fechas, avisos de la app en la barra de estado o.O TANTAS COSAS!!

Comment: Hehehe pues agrega las preguntas Erny

Comment: podrias agregarme al face (mi usuario es exactamente igual que este)? o cualquier red que tu prefieras... si es de preguntar algo... quiero aprender a descifrar este ejercicio de aprender o entenderlo en su totalidad solventaría todo lo de base de datos ( o la gran mayoria referente a eso ps) http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/01/base-de-datos-sqlite-en-android-con-multiples-tablas/